# What created `maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle`?

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk, part-of-speech

The `nltk` package's built-in part-of-speech tagger does not seem to be optimized for my use-case ([here, for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349851/provoke-the-nltk-part-of-speech-tagger-to-report-a-plural-proper-noun)).  The [source code here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag.html) shows that it's using a saved, pre-trained classifier called `maxent_treebank_pos_tagger`.

What created `maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle`?  I'm guessing that there is a tagged corpus out there somewhere that was used to train this tagger, so I think I'm looking for (a) that tagged corpus and (b) the exact code that trains the tagger based on the tagged corpus.

In addition to lots of googling, so far I tried to look at the `.pickle` object directly to find any clues inside it, starting like this

```
from nltk.data import load
x = load("nltk_data/taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle")
dir(x)
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I believe the corpus used is the [Penn Treebank](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/)

Comment: @Igor, the source code I liked to above seems to agree.  Unfortunately, it seems like maybe the Penn Treebank data is not free to the public, which would mostly answer my question:  https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC99T42

Answer (score 6):

The NLTK source is [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/**init**.py#L83](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/__init__.py#L83)

The original source of NLTK's MaxEnt POS tagger is from https://github.com/arne-cl/nltk-maxent-pos-tagger

**Training Data**: Wall Street Journal subset of the Penn Tree bank corpus

**Features**: [Ratnaparki (1996)](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W/W96/W96-0213.pdf)

**Algorithm**: Maximum Entropy

**Accuracy**: [What is the accuracy of nltk pos_tagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108053/what-is-the-accuracy-of-nltk-pos-tagger)

Comment: Your second link ( https://github.com/arne-cl/nltk-maxent-pos-tagger) is the part that seems to directly address my question.  How do you know that this is the same `nltk-maxent-pos-tagger` as shows up in the official `nltk` package?

Comment: Why not raise an issue on the nltk github as well?